# Spring @Async for Cloudinary upload not working - program stops without any exception

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, cloudinary

Recently I implemented uploading images to Cloudinary API in Spring.

Eveything works fine (when running NOT async), but when I want to refactor my `uploadImage` method to work asynchronous, program goes through till the moment, when `Cloudinary.uploader().upload(...)` is called. In that place program stops without throwing any exception.

- When I get rid of `Cloudinary.uploader().upload(...)`, the whole async method works fine.

**Here's my configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig {
}
```

**Controller's endpoint when @Async method is called:**

```
@PostMapping(path = "/uploadImage/{productId}")
    public void uploadImage(@PathVariable("productId") Long productId,
                            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        ImageToUpload imageToUpload = new ImageToUpload(); //my custom entity used just for validation, don't focus on it
        imageToUpload.setFile(file);
        productService.uploadImage(imageToUpload, productId); //<--- Here is @Async method call
    }
```

**Service with Async method:**

```
    @Override
    @Async
    @Transactional
    public CompletableFuture<Void> uploadImage(final ImageToUpload imageToUpload, final Long productId) {
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            ProductDTO productDTO = findById(productId);
            ImageDTO imageDTO = imageService.createNewImage(imageToUpload); // <-- here program stops without any exception
            productDTO.setImageId(imageDTO.getId());
            update(productId, productDTO);
        });
    }
```

**createNewImage() method:**

```
public ImageDTO createNewImage(final ImageToUpload imageToUpload) {
        Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload( // <-- here's the problem - when Cloundinary tries to upload image and never ending 
                imageToUpload.getFile().getBytes(),
                ObjectUtils.asMap("resource_type", "auto")
        );
        imageToUpload.setParams(uploadResult);
        Image image = imageRepository.save(
                new Image(uploadResult.get("url").toString(), imageToUpload.getPreloadedFile())
        );
        log.info("Image: " + image.getTitle() + " saved and uploaded successfully.");
        return imageMapper.toDto(image);
    }
```

- When I call `.get()` on async method in controller everything work, but in that case, Async is useless. It is weird, because in my previous projects all async methods were working fine without `get()` (they were returning `Void`, so there wasn't need to call it on them).

Has anyone faced this problem? I have no idea what else can I do to make it work async.

I'll be thankful for any help.

Comment: If you don't want to wait for the completion of the method in your controller, and not need the response, then you don't have to build and return a CompletableFuture. Have you tried a simple "void" @Async method?

Comment: Yes, I've tried. Didn't work.